# chrome, firefox and safari page looks different

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I made a site using a template someone else purchased and I made modifications to it quickly and uploaded it splurg .co

I am working on the live app and have been away from webDev for a while and would love to know why on my system in three different browsers the page seems to react differently. And what I can do to figure out how to fix each page / or my setup ?

the page in question and on my chrome does not show a backgoround image and in firefox it renders.

I am curious on how I can figure this out myself, I've look at dev tools and it appears to get the image just never loads it.

Since I checked the site at work using chrome ( and it worked there )  I added an screenshot, since it seems to just fail on my own personal system and no where else ?

[image]

Comment: You've posted no code, so how are we expected to help troubleshoot the issue(s)?

Comment: You need to be more specific if you want help. But the if the image in question is the one with the three women, then it loads for me on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common issue with different browsers. A google search on cross browser compatibility will give you a lot of reading material as well as resources to help solve the issue. Different browsers use different parsers and rendering engines. As such, different browsers yield different results of the same website. That is why IE is one of the most hated browsers by web developers. It usually has to do with CSS. For example, some CSS properties are not honored in certain browsers and sometimes you have to prefix the property with browser specific prefix to make it work like `-moz-box-sizing` Notice the `-moz-` prefix.

Also, if your template is using CSS3 that is a whole another bag of worms. Hope it was helpful and happy coding.